# Matplotlib multiple colours in tick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to have an tick labels formatted with different colours within the label

eg Using labels like this:

```
labels = ['apple - 1 : 7', 'orange - 5 : 10']
```

Such that the numbers 1 & 5 appear blue and 7 & 10 appear red?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the object-oriented interface of matplotlib to plot your data, you can use the [get_xticklabels](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html?highlight=get_xticklabels#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xticklabels) and [get_yticklabels](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html?highlight=get_yticklabels#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_yticklabels) to access the labels of each axis and then change the color of the ones you want.

**EDIT :** I misunderstood the original question. See below for a more appropriate answer.

One of the possibility is to remove the original labels and create pseudo-labels using a text instance. This way, you can create text with different color inside. It is not straightforwad (you will have to write a lot of code, especially  if you have a lot of labels you want to multi-colorize), but below is an example of what you can do.

The idea is to create the different parts of each label in the color you want using the `matplotlib.offsetbox.TextArea` method, and then merge them using the `matplotlib.offsetbox.HPacker` method (I discovered the HPacker method via [this post](http://abitofpythonabitofastronomy.blogspot.com/2009/05/mpl-multicolor-text.html)).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredOffsetbox, TextArea, HPacker

fig = plt.subplots(1)

ax.bar([0, 1], [20, 35], 0.35, color='0.5', yerr=[2, 3], ecolor='k')
ax.set_xlim([-0.2, 1.7])
ax.set_xticks([]) # empty xticklabels

# apple label
abox1 = TextArea("apple - ", textprops=dict(color="k", size=15))
abox2 = TextArea("1 ", textprops=dict(color="b", size=15))
abox3 = TextArea(": ", textprops=dict(color="k", size=15))
abox4 = TextArea("7 ", textprops=dict(color="r", size=15))

applebox = HPacker(children=[abox1, abox2, abox3, abox4],
                  align="center", pad=0, sep=5)

# orange label
obox1 = TextArea("orange - ", textprops=dict(color="k", size=15))
obox2 = TextArea("5 ", textprops=dict(color="b", size=15))
obox3 = TextArea(": ", textprops=dict(color="k", size=15))
obox4 = TextArea("10 ", textprops=dict(color="r", size=15))

orangebox = HPacker(children=[obox1, obox2, obox3, obox4],
                    align="center", pad=0, sep=5)

anchored_applebox = AnchoredOffsetbox(loc=3, child=applebox, pad=0., frameon=False,
                                      bbox_to_anchor=(0.1, -0.07),
                                      bbox_transform=ax.transAxes, borderpad=0.)

anchored_orangebox = AnchoredOffsetbox(loc=3, child=orangebox, pad=0., frameon=False,
                                       bbox_to_anchor=(0.6, -0.07),
                                       bbox_transform=ax.transAxes, borderpad=0.)

ax.add_artist(anchored_applebox)
ax.add_artist(anchored_orangebox)

plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image: appleorange]

Comment: If I understand the OP right, he wants to know if it is "possible to have an tick labels formatted with different colours **within** the label". Your approach will change the colour of the whole tick label.

Comment: @bmu Yes, looks like I totally misunderstood the question