# Changing text appearance of a part of a xticks string

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def xtick_labels(time_range):
        labels = [
        i.strftime("%H:%M\n%Y-%m-%d")
        if (i.strftime("%H:%M:%S") == "00:00:00")
        else i.strftime("%H:%M")
        for i in time_range
    ]
        return labels


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 4))
time_range = pd.date_range('01.01.2020 00:00:00', '01.03.2020 01:00:00', freq='2H')
ax.plot(time_range, len(time_range)*[1])
labels = xtick_labels(time_range)
ax.set_xticks(time_range, labels);
```

[image]

Is it possible to only change the appereance of a part of the dates in that xticks? Like changing the colour, different size?
So not changing the entire xtick.

I know that changing the entire xtick is possible with:

```
ax.get_xticklabels()[-1].set_fontsize(14)
ax.get_xticklabels()[-1].set_color('red')
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can adapt this answer to your needs? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49041502/8310295

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325765/matplotlib-multiple-colours-in-tick-labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible, but I think an easier approach would be to use custom annotations, instead of making the ticks do two separate things at once.

In this modified code, I store the location and text for the dates you want in red.  Then, I loop through these locations and text values and annotate them onto the figure, using `ax.annotate` which I think is a better fit for what you are trying to accomplish:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def annotations(time_range):
    data = []
    annotations = []
    for i in time_range:
        # If we want a custom tick, store it's data point and annotation
        if (i.strftime("%H:%M:%S") == "00:00:00"):
            data.append(i)
            annotations.append(i.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    return data, annotations

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 4))
time_range = pd.date_range('01.01.2020 00:00:00', '01.03.2020 01:00:00', freq='2H')
ax.plot(time_range, len(time_range)*[1])
labels = [i.strftime("%H:%M") for i in time_range]
ax.set_xticks(time_range, labels)

location, annnotations = annotations(time_range)
for x_loc, ann in zip(location, annnotations):
    y_loc = .93
    ax.annotate(
        text=ann,              # The text we are appending to the figure
        xy=(x_loc, y_loc),     # The (x,y) coordinates of that text in the axes DATA coordinates
        annotation_clip=False, # Tell MPL to not clip annotations outside of the axes range
        color='red', 
        fontsize=14, 
        ha='center',
        va='center'
    )
```

This produces what you want, and I think is clearer than trying to do some intense tick label customization.  Notice that I hard-coded `y_loc` to be 0.93, which corresponds to the value of .93 on your y-axis where I wanted the annotations to be.  You could probably automate this by getting the lower y limit of your axis and subtracting some constant value, but I did not do this for simplicity.

[image: The figure with certain dates in red]